# Rounding an SQL calculation Alias result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(myColumnOne) from myTableOne) / (SELECT SUM(myColumnTwo) FROM myTableTwo) * 100 AS myResult;
```

What I want is to have just one decimal place in the resulting alias myResult. I've tried using SELECT ROUND but haven't been able to achieve this. I'm basically calculating one table column as the percentage of another so if there's an even cleaner way to to this I'd like that too!

Any and all help welcome - thanks!

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROUND()` should do it.

```
SELECT ROUND((SELECT SUM(myColumnOne) from myTableOne) / 
             (SELECT SUM(myColumnTwo) FROM myTableTwo) * 100, 1) AS myResult
```

Comment: Many thanks Barmar, that is perfect.  I had the comma incorrectly ordered.